# In hadoop, 1 reduce or number of reduces = number of mappers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In hadoop, what is the difference between using n mappers and n reduce, or n mappers and 1 reduce.
in the case of using 1 reduce, the reduce phase is made of which computer (mappers), if I have 3 computers

Comment: Your reducers control the output files. You cannot control which computer runs it

Comment: thank you, if i want to use hadoop for storage and big data processing, do I have to realize (clients and servers)  ?

Comment: You need to acquire hardware, install and configure it, yes... Same for any server

Answer (score 0):

The number of mappers is controlled by the amount of data being processed. Reducers are controlled either by the developer or different system parameters.

To override the number of reducers:
set mapreduce.job.reduces=#;

or if it is a Hive job and you want to control more how much work each reducer has to do then you can tweak certain parameters such as:
hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer.

You can still override by using mapreduce.job.reduces it is just using the bytes per reducer allows you to control the amount each reducer processes.

In regards to controlling where the reducers run you really cannot control that except by using Node Labels. This would mean controlling where all of the tasks in the job run not just the reducers.